# Python intercalate variable output

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I need to translate a DNA sequence to its corresponding amino acid sequence. I have the whole program written, but I'm having difficulties with the way in which the output is being produced.

In summary, I have this code:

```
for x in f1:
    x = x.strip()
    if x.count("seq"):
        f2.write((x)+("_1_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_2_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_3_+\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_1_-\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_2_-\n"))
        f2.write((x)+("_3_-\n"))
    else:
        f2.write((translate1(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate2(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate3(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate1neg(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate2neg(x))+("\n"))
        f2.write((translate3neg(x))+("\n"))
```

that gives this output:

```
>seq1_1_+
>seq1_2_+
>seq1_3_+
>seq1_1_-
>seq1_2_-
>seq1_3_-
iyyslrs-las-smrlssiv-m
fiirydrs-ladrcgshrssk
llfativas-lidaalidrl
frrsmraasis-lativannkm
lddr-ephrsas-lrs-riin
-tidesridqlasydrse--m
```

But what i need is something like this:

```
>seq1_1_+
iyyslrs-las-smrlssiv-m
>seq1_2_+
fiirydrs-ladrcgshrssk
>seq1_3_+
llfativas-lidaalidrl
>seq1_1_-
frrsmraasis-lativannkm
>seq1_2_-
lddr-ephrsas-lrs-riin
>seq1_3_-
-tidesridqlasydrse--m
```

So, my question is, how can i resolve this?

Comment: You are printing them together. It's obvious why the output is so...

Comment: Looks like you're mixing things that don't fit well together into one data structure. Please post your whole program, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

```
# First store data.
sequence = []
translated = []

for x in f1:
    x = x.strip()
    if x.count("sequence"):
        sequence.append((x)+("_1_+\n"))
        sequence.append((x)+("_2_+\n"))
        sequence.append((x)+("_3_+\n"))
        sequence.append((x)+("_1_-\n"))
        sequence.append((x)+("_2_-\n"))
        sequence.append((x)+("_3_-\n"))
    else:
        translated.append((translate1(x))+("\n"))
        translated.append((translate2(x))+("\n"))
        translated.append((translate3(x))+("\n"))
        translated.append((translate1neg(x))+("\n"))
        translated.append((translate2neg(x))+("\n"))
        translated.append((translate3neg(x))+("\n"))

# and then write it to file.

for s, t in zip(sequence, translated):
    f2.write(s)
    f2.write(t)
```